# Reading and writing .csv file with newline

Tags: java

I have a .csv file that looks like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
1,2,3,4,5
```

I am doing something like this:

```
//Read stream
File myFile = new File("C:\\testFile.csv");
InputStreamReader isTest = new InputStreamReader(myStream);
StringBuilder sbTest = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader brTest = new BufferedReader(isTest );
String readTest = brTest.readLine();

while(readTest != null) {
    sbTest .append(readTest);
    readTest = brTest.readLine();
}

//Write stream

FileWriter fwTest = new FileWriter(myFile .getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bwTest = new BufferedWriter(fwTest);

bwTest .write(sbTest.toString());
bwTest .close();
```

However, when I open the file, I see the following CSV:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col51,2,3,4,5
```

Is there a way to parse the newline and make sure that is appended when I write to a file?

Comment: what is your `myStream` ?

Comment: You need to append the newline as you are bringing lines into `sbTest`.

Comment: im not sure if you want to use the stringbuilder. otherwise you want to add a newline character after every append

Comment: myStream is the .csv file

Comment: if you didnt define `myStream`, how did you run your program?

Comment: dude....Im just not showing all the code...this is a webservice that has alot of other moving parts...just take my word for it :)

Comment: why did some clown downvote this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is append a newline to your StringBuilder. To make it platform-independent, use your system's line.separator property, like so:

```
sbTest.append(readTest).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

When you write the string to your BufferWriter, call `trim()` on that string to remove the dangling newline.

```
bwTest.write(sbTest.toString().trim());
```

---

As dkatzel suggests, you may also want to bring out the line separator into a constant. Something like this:

```
private static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Your while-loop would then include this:

```
sbTest.append(readTest).append(NEWLINE);
```

Comment: might be better to pull the property value out as a constant since you only need to look it up once.